What is the view on TRT for Catholics?

Testosterone replacement therapy (TRT) is a widely used treatment for
men with symptomatic hypogonadism. The benefits seen with TRT, such as
increased libido and energy level, beneficial effects on bone density,
strength and muscle as well as cardioprotective effects, have been
well-documented. Source

I am seeking the Catholic perspective on a particular type of treatment that seems to border on the use of drugs and hormonal enhancements, which bear similarities to contraceptives used by women or steroid use by bodybuilders. Specifically, I am referring to Testosterone Replacement Therapy (TRT). I understand that TRT does not have contraceptive effects in men, but it is a hormonal treatment that can potentially give men certain advantages in life. These advantages could be perceived as being outside of God’s plan.
This treatment appears to require a lifelong commitment and, while it does provide health benefits, there may also be some drawbacks.
From a moral perspective, should a Catholic man feel at ease proceeding with this kind of treatment after consulting with a doctor? I am interested in understanding the ethical implications of this decision within the context of Catholic teachings.

Hormone therapies that assist natural bodily functions are moral.
For example, for women, Catholic OB/GYN Dr. Thomas W. Hilgers, MD's advocates monitoring hormone levels during pregnancy and giving needed progesterone support, so as to prevent preterm birth. See: Hilgers, The NaProTECHNOLOGY Revolution, chapters 20 & 39.
